# Como alterar o valor de uma string no XML?

Tags: java, android, xml

Existe um modo de alterar um valor de uma string no XML.

Sei como pegar o valor através do `getResource().getString(R.string.value);` mas não sei alterar o valor diretamente no XML. Isso é permitido? Ou os valores criados no XML são constantes (imutáveis)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo [essa resposta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5233137/520779), o que você quer não é possível - o `string.xml` de fato é somente-leitura. A alternativa recomendada é usar [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html): um meio de criar e persistir dados de preferências do usuário.

[Nesse link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) tem um exemplo de como utilizá-las (caso essa alternativa realmente te atenda, é claro):

```
public class Calc extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
       super.onCreate(state);
       . . .

       // Recupera as preferências salvas
       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
       setSilent(silent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
       super.onStop();

      // Atribui uma nova preferência; isso é feito através de um Editor
      // Todos os objetos são de android.context.Context
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

      // Confirma as edições
      editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado. Vou estudar esse SharedPreferences , creio que seja isso realmente.

Comment: @Zeca Você pode aceitar esta resposta como a correta, deixando claro para todos que ela solucionou o problema e dando reputação para você e o autor da resposta.